# Is Primefaces addRow feature compatible with lazyloading datatable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to use addRow feature `onclick="PF('auditDataVar').addRow();"`to add a row to a lazyloaded datatable as below. It is inserting a duplicate of last row instead of a blank row. So wondering if this addRow feature even works with lazy loading?! Or am I missing something?

Difference between [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/addRow.xhtml) and my code are 1. lazy loading and 2. Inserting from (menuitem inside) Context Menu instead of Command button.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Primefaces 6.1, JSF 2.2

```
<p:menuitem value="Insert row" icon="fa fa-plus" 
                              actionListener="#{auditBean.insertRow()}" 
                              oncomplete="PF('auditDataVar').addRow();" />

<p:dataTable id="auditData" widgetVar="auditDataVar" var="aud" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="460" scrollWidth="1900" resizableColumns="true" value="#{auditBean.audits}" editable="true" paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                               selection="#{auditBean.selectedAudit}" selectionMode="single"  rowKey="#{aud.accountabilityElementId}_#{aud.comboRowKey}" rows="100" lazy="true" emptyMessage="No audits found">
```

Managed Bean:

```
        public void insertRow() {
        selectedItem = new AccountabilityAuditEntity();
         selectedItem.setComboRowKey(insertCount + 1); //to set rowkey for new row
        if (lazyAudit.getEntries() != null) {
            lazyAudit.getEntries().add(selectedItem); 
            lazyAudit.setRowCount(lazyAudit.getRowCount()+1); 
        } else {
            AccountabilityAuditEntity newAudit = new AccountabilityAuditEntity();
            newAudit.setComboRowKey(insertCount + 1);
            auditDetailData.add(newAudit);
            lazyAudit.setEntries(auditDetailData);//setting ArrayList to lazymodel
            lazyAudit.setRowCount(1);
        }
        insertCount++;

        audits = lazyAudit; //list audits is used by the datatable 
        selectedAudit = null;
    }
```

Comment: You did not post your auditBean.insertRow() Java code for us to view.

Comment: Apologies, added the insertRow() code. Thanks.

Comment: OK now I am suspicious of your comboRowKey and that somehow PF is getting the wrong row value when you add your new row without an aud.accountabilityElementId.  I feel like PF would not duplicate the values in the last row when your bean is empty unless for some reason it thinks that it is the last row.  I am not ruling out a bug in the Datatable but the above code does seem strange.  Can you create an MVCE http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ with simplified values to try and narrow it down.

Comment: I also can see from the thread of the original ticket other people had the same issue as you but never responded back:  https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1169

Comment: Thanks @Melloware. I removed the comboRowKey but still the issue persists. Yes it looks like a bug with the addRow feature. Lines 37 & 38 from the [source code link](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/09848d4db7a6f9101a4806f82fd24fbf59cc47ff/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/datatable/feature/AddRowFeature.java) may be the reason why it inserts a duplicate of last row. I am switching to explicit refresh of the table after insertRow() which has performance impact :(

Comment: Ok let me see if I can reproduce. I will let you know what I find out.

Comment: OK I created a test case and reported the bug to PF team below...

Comment: OK I found a solution to your problem and edited my answer below to contain the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

OK I was able to get your solution working by adding the code below in between START and STOP.  See this ticket: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3901

```
public void insertRow() {
    selectedItem = new AccountabilityAuditEntity();
    selectedItem.setComboRowKey(insertCount + 1); //to set rowkey for new row
    if (lazyAudit.getEntries() != null) {
         lazyAudit.getEntries().add(selectedItem); 
    } else {
         AccountabilityAuditEntity newAudit = new AccountabilityAuditEntity();
         newAudit.setComboRowKey(insertCount + 1);
         auditDetailData.add(newAudit);
         lazyAudit.setEntries(auditDetailData);//setting ArrayList to lazymodel
    }

    // START
    lazyAudit.setRowCount(lazyAudit.getEntries().size());
    lazyModel.setWrappedData(lazyAudit.getEntries());
    // STOP

    insertCount++;

    audits = lazyAudit; //list audits is used by the datatable 
    selectedAudit = null;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay to respond. I tried the above but it didn't work.But with the help of your sample code in the github link, I modified it to mimic our lazy datatable and found a bug - it adds a duplicate in current page but adds the blank row to the last page. To work around this I had to disable 'Add Row' for other pages except last page. Let me post the code I tried as answer. Thanks for the code and effort.

Comment: On that GitHub ticket feel free to post your updated primefaces-test.zip so I can see it and run it.  It stinks Stack Overflow doesn't allow file uploads!